# Zend Json_Encode and .getJson success not being called?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I have a script that I am using to return some JSON from PHP using the Zend Framework.

This is what I get back: []{"Test":"Tester"} but the success function in jQuery isn't being called. Shouldn't the json be [{"Test":"Tester"}]?

In my controller I did this:

```
echo Zend_Json::encode(array("Test" => "Tester"));
```

Client Js:

```
  $.getJSON("/entry/get-projects",
    {
        "id": 1,
        "format": "json"
    },
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert("win");
    }
    );
```

Comment: If I return nothing, the success function triggers the alert.

Comment: try using firebug's console to see exactly what Zend is sending and how it is sending it.

Comment: It is sending back this text in firebug:  []{"Test":"Tester"}

Comment: also what version of ZF are you using? what version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action that is handling the json call

```
$callback = $this->getRequest()->getParam('callback');
echo $callback . '(' . Zend_Json::encode(array('key' => 'value')) . ')';
```

In your JS

```
var map = {
    'key1'  : val1,
    'key2'  : val2
};

$.post('/some/ajax-action/', map, some_callback_function, 'json');
```

Failing that, you could always try:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
echo json_encode(array('key' => 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using 
`$this->_helper->json();` as mentioned here: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/08/13/returning-json-in-a-zend-controllers-action/

Not sure if there is a better way. For example: Propel has a nifty toJSON method that kicks back json code from your query result. It would suck to convert it to an array using propel and then have to convert it to JSON with Zend.